# Ubuntu installation hangs at certain level

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

When I try to install/run Ubuntu from a liveCD, it just hangs on following screen...

[image]

Any ideas?

I've unplugged all my usb devices other than my death adder mouse and g15 keyboard, tried 32bit and 64bit 11.10 but both do the same thing.

Ran the memory test on the ubuntu install CD and it was fine.

My PC specifications are:
Motherboard : *Asus P5Q*
Processor: *Intel Core 2 Quad Q6700*
Memory/RAM : *4GB dominator 1066mhz corsair*
HDD: *1TB*
Graphics Card : *Asus 560ti*

edit : after unplugging all my usb devices (putting a new keyboard in) and disabling firewire on my motherboard in the bios, I get the image below...

[image]

Comment: It looks like your G15 is stopping the boot. Try another keyboard?